# Как повесить событие на изменение контента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Гружу таблицу, которая берется из `БД mysql` в файле `table.php`

```
var seconds = 1;
var divid = "responsecontainer";
var url = "table.php";

function refreshdiv() {

  var xmlHttp;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Для нормальных браузеров
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // ....
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        alert("Твой браузер не поддерживает AJAX.");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      setTimeout('refreshdiv()', seconds * 1000);
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Проблема в том, что никак не могу повесить `alert` реагирующий на изменения (добавления новой строки, удаление старой, `etc`) в `div-e` с `id responsecontainer`. Как это можно сделать, пробовал такой скрипт:

```
$('responsecontainer').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
alert('changed'); });
```

Но он реагировал на все.

Comment: вот поэтому надо передавать данные, на основе которых строить разметку, а не просто разметку, и по ней пытаться понять какие данные были

Comment: _он реагировал на все_ - потому что в строке `document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;` ты и меняешь _все_